# Java:Creating an Object from Class

Tags: java, class, object, new-operator

We are just getting into objects and I came across an issue. Given the following class I created...

```
public class employee{
    String name;
    int waiting_time;
    int retaining_time;

    public employee(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void setWaitingTime(int waitingtime)
    {
        waiting_time = waitingtime;
    }

    public int getWaitingTime()
    {
        return waiting_time;
    }

    public void setRetainingTime(int retainingtime)
    {
        retaining_time = retainingtime;
    }

    public int getRetainingTime()
    {
        return retaining_time;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a function that creates an instance of this class, and then sets `waiting_time` and `retaining_time` to `0` for only the first time it's created. Those two values will be added/subtracted upon later in the program, but they must be `0` at the start.

```
public static void addEmployee(String aName)
{
    employee anEmployee = new employee();  //error here says library.employee() is undefined?
}
```

I've done it exactly how they've done it in our book, not sure where I'm going wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where's that `.addEmployee()` method? In what class? Also, how are you compiling the project? Using `javac`? Usin an IDE (eclipse)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add this constructor

```
public employee(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}
```

there is no default constructor without parameters. A default constructor is only generated for you if you do not write any constructors yourself. If you want a constructor with no parameters in addition to this other one, you have to add it

```
public employee() { }
```

By the way, classes in Java normally begin with a capital letter.

Comment: Okay, so it would make more sense to have a default constructor `public employee() {}`, and then create something such as `setName` and `getName` for the name instead of what I had?

Comment: I normally make a constructor which sets all the fields, and then only provide get methods. There are loads of ways of writing classes, so you can choose how you want them.

Comment: makes sense, and then the instantiation call of it would just be `Employee anEmployee = new employee()` then `anEmployee.setName("Bob")` or something of that nature?

Answer (score 1):

Add following constructor in your class

```
public employee()
{
    this.waiting_time=0;
    this.retaining_time=0;
}
```

The error is due to the absence of default constructor as you have added another constructor. Since you wanted to set `waiting_time` and `retaining_time` to 0; so I have just done the same in this constructor

Comment: would I then just have to create a setName and getName?

Comment: @user38254 you can do that or you can simply create your object using the constructor you created by passing string object and set the `waiting_time` and `retaining_time` in it

Answer (score 0):

Your only constructor for the class requires a String as an argument. You need to pass the string as an argument:

```
employee anEmployee = new employee(aName);
```

Comment: Thats what I thought would work but it gives me an error-- No enclosing instance of type library accessible.